# $api->lists(); is empty for new mailchimp account API keys

Tags: php, mailchimp

So I am calling $api->lists(); on an existing account and it returns an array of mailing lists. When I swap out the API key for one in a new account which has two existing lists, calling the same  $api->lists(); returns empty. Why would swapping out the API key break the lists(); and what are some possible solutions.

I am using MCAPI v1.1 and PHP.

```
$apikey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-usx';
$api = new MCAPI($apikey);
dpm($api->lists()); // drupal print message
```

Edit: The solution to this was to swap out v1.1 for v1.3 of the MCAPI. I didn't really investigate the changes between these versions, but upgrading to v1.3 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was to swap out v1.1 for v1.3 of the MCAPI. I didn't really investigate the changes between these versions, but upgrading to v1.3 fixed it for me.